# How to api call with findQuery in adapter?

Tags: ember.js

Im trying to make an api call from my ember app.

I have an url format like this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/movies?where={"title": { "contains" : "" }, "year": "", "active": { "!" : "false" }}
```

But i dont know how to pass variables title, years, etc to the api call in the adapter.

I already have something like this:

```
export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
namespace: movies,
host: 'http:// xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx’,
buildURL: function(type, id, record){
  console.log("Building URL: ", type);
  var url = this._super(type, id, record);
  console.log("Building URL: ", url);
  return url;
 }
});
```

I think i need something like [findQuery](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/finding-records/) but I dont know how to use it. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `ActiveModelAdapter` or [rails](/questions/tagged/rails), but isn't `movies` the plural form of `movie` which is your model name? In that case you shouldn't have a namespace `movies`. The namespace is the prefix like if you have `/api/v1` **before** the model name. Like `http://<your_domain>/api/v1/<model_name>`.

EmberJS query must be a key value pair. And URL's don't support that structure (they would need ot be URLencoded). You can however convert your object into JSON before making the query:

```
var whereQuery = {"title": { "contains" : "" }, "year": "", "active": { "!" : "false" }}
this.store.query('movie', {where: JSON.stringify(whereQuery}))
```

So your adapter should *probably* just be left empty like this:

```
export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again, youre my hero!!